# Cannot get whenever to run my rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

I am trying to get `whenever` to run my rake task but it doesn't work.

```
#Command Line
$ whenever -w
[write] crontab file written


#schedule.rb
every :year, :at => "2014-07-25 17:39:48 -0700" do
  rake 'timeperiod:create_timeperiod'
end
```

The rake command saves a model in the db and `puts` text so I would know if it worked (which it does when I run `rake`).  Is there syntactically something wrong with what I did?

Note, the time and date in `schedule.rb` is arbitrary, I keep changing it to two minutes from now before testing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There were a couple issues here.

1. The best way to add cron jobs to whenever is with the command `whenever --update-crontab <name of identifier>`
2. The format was incorrect.  By specifying the time in cron directly, I was able to make it work.

For example:

```
#schedule.rb
every '13 15 26 7 *' do
  rake 'timeperiod:create_timeperiod'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your task is probably failing because the shell used by cron is not the same you use with your normal user.

Check the log of the crontab:

```
grep CRON  /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: You're right, I got "no such directory" when I ran this.  Do you know how I can sync shells here?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you verify that your command is getting added to the crontab?

```
$ crontab -l
```

You can also add the job manually.

```
$ whenever
* * * * * * bash -l 'cd /path/to/dir; rake your:task'

$ crontab -e
# add the cron job
```

Also, output from cron jobs doesn't output to the screen; it goes to your mail. Check your mailbox.

From the man page:

> When executing commands, any output is mailed to the owner of the
>   crontab (or to the user named in the MAILTO environment variable in
>   the crontab, if such exists). The children copies of cron running
>   these processes have their name coerced to uppercase, as will be seen
>   in the syslog and ps output.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I'm using command but I think it's not the best case. Says my repo is in $HOME/www/virtualspirit, in my repository. So my whenever command will be cd /www/virtualspirit && /$HOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/rake timeperiod:create_timeperiod RAILS_ENV=production

double check it in crontab -e and see whether it saved.

Comment: My output after `crontab -e` is in this pastie: http://pastie.org/9423365  Suffice it to say, the command was saved.

Comment: @EricBaldwin is this development or production? your pastie show it using development, and the command generated i think it in correct, from the command you show me, you can just try to execute it in your $HOME path with cd ~ && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake timeperiod:create_timeperiod --silent

Comment: I think it will not execute your task...try it and see

Comment: It is in development.  I found an answer, I just can't accept it for 15 hours because of Stack Overflow's structure